# Accessing SMS gateway from php application

Tags: php

I have finally(with stackoverflow's help and Darhazer)..gotten to the final stage of my sms application.The last hurdle is that the gateway api is not sending the sms messages from my application.However when i place it directly on the address bar and call it,it works. I am using cURL in a loop to send it.Please point me in the right direction. My UPDATED code is:

```
      <?php

    include 'sms_connect.php';
    $sql="select name,number from sms";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Error in sms".mysqli_error($link));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $name=$row['name'];
     $number=$row['number'];


 $url="http://xx1.yyw.wwe.bbb:8912/bulksms/
 bulksms?username=qqq&password=zzz&type=0&dlr=Z&destination=".urlencode($number)."&source=bbb&message=".urlencode($name);

   $ch = curl_init();


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$results = curl_exec($ch);


    }
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Do not put any characters before first <?php if you use sessions or changing headers

Comment: where is $number coming from ?

Comment: Removed characters..no change

Comment: Once again, you are not urlencoding $number and $name (and browser usually do this for you when you paste address in the location bar)

Comment: $result is the container for the result,$number is a container for the phone numbers in the database

Comment: IT WORKs!!! IT WORKS...thanks all of you guys...especially Darhazer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true and see what the result equals then - maybe something related to the remote site

Echo the $url and ensure its correct - ie what you expect

Comment: actually, check `if ($result !== FALSE)`. curl could very well return a legitimate `0` or `1`, if that's what the site spits out. Checking against boolean false in strict comparison mode is the proper method to check for failure.